# Nuxt/Vuejs Need to implement Auth on some components that are having click event binding

Tags: vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js, vue-directives

In my nuxt application, the auth is managed by **nuxt-auth module**.

I have to show the data in both cases with and without auth. But without auth the click event should render a login dialog instead of actual callback.

I have written a directive`v-auth` but I am unable to unbind the click event listener from vnode component.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add code as well for use to see what you have tried yet and for a better understanding of the question too? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
export default {
   bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
      vnode.componentInstance.$off('click')
   }
}
```